# Equivalent resistance of this circuit, equality between two points confusing

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance

[image: This is the image of the circuit provided]

Also, it is stated that the equivalent resistance between AC is same as that between BC.

But $\frac{1}{R_{AC}} = \frac{1}{10} + \frac{1}{14}$

Which on looking and calculating is not equal to $R_{AC}$.

Can someone explain how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's calculate the equivalent resitance between A and C. For that, first note that the two resitors of $3\Omega$ and $5\Omega$ that are on the extremities B and D don't contribute anything to the equivalent reistance. Moreover, note how you can combine the three resistors of $4\Omega$, $6\Omega$, and $4\Omega$ into a single $14\Omega$ resistor that is associated in parallel with the $2\Omega$ resistor in the top. Their equivalent resitance is then given by $\frac{1}{R} = \frac{1}{2\Omega}+\frac{1}{14\Omega} \iff R=\frac{7}{4}\Omega$. Now you just need to add that to the $5\Omega$ and $3\Omega$ in the extremities A and C to get $5\Omega+3\Omega+\frac{7}{4}\Omega=\frac{39}{4}\Omega \implies R_{AC}=\frac{39}{4}\Omega$.

Now let's calculate the equivalent resitance between B and C. For that, first note that the two resitors of $5\Omega$ and $5\Omega$ that are on the extremities A and D don't contribute anything to the equivalent reistance. Moreover, note how you can combine the two resitors of $6\Omega$ and $4\Omega$ into a resistor of $10\Omega$, and the two resitors of $4\Omega$ and $2\Omega$ into a resistor of $6\Omega$. These two (the $10\Omega$ and the $6\Omega$ resistors) are associated in parallel, so their equivalent resitance is then given by $\frac{1}{R} = \frac{1}{6\Omega}+\frac{1}{10\Omega} \iff R=\frac{15}{4}\Omega$. Now you just need to add that to the $3\Omega$ and $3\Omega$ in the extremities B and C to get $3\Omega+3\Omega+\frac{15}{4}\Omega=\frac{39}{4}\Omega \implies R_{BC}=\frac{39}{4}\Omega$.

This shows $R_{AC}=R_{BC}=\frac{39}{4}\Omega$

Comment: Why will we consider that 2 ohm along side 14 ohm in parallel ? My idea was that 5,3,2 ohm is in series and to this entire straight line, 14 ohm is in parallel.